# Problems solving a nonlinear PDE with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic, nonlinear

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier, persisting in part through 11.3.**

---

I was willing to solve this nonlinear PDE:

```
DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] 0.5 w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] 0.5 w1 - w1 == 0, 
 l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}]
```

Any general solution is ok, so I didn't include boundary conditions. My goal is only to find out if there is a l[w1,w2] that solves the equation. Mathematica isn't outputting anything. What is it I'm getting wrong?

**EDIT**

I would like to point out that such a solution may easily be found by hand. For instance this already is a possible solution:

$l=-2*w2+A(w1^2 + w2^2)$

with A being any constant.

Comment: When plotting numerically I get the warning: `"No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for \
{l}; the result is not unique up to a constant"`

Comment: Sorry, would you paste your bits of code. I don't receive any result at all. I don't expect the result to be unique as I have not specified any sort of boundary condition. I'm just interested in verifying that \{l} exists. @Feyre

Comment: Like I said, I could only solve it numerically: `s=NDSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] 0.5 w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] 0.5 w1 - w1 == 0, 
 l[w1, w2], {w1, 0, 3}, {w2, 0, 3}][[1,1,2]]`. Plot with: `Plot3D[s, {w1, 0., 3.}, {w2, 0., 3.}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution can be obtained easily using `DSolve`, if `0.5` is replaced by `1/2`.

```
Flatten@DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1]  w2/2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] w1/2 - w1 == 0, 
    l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}]
(* {l[w1, w2] -> -2 Sqrt[w2^2] + C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)], 
    l[w1, w2] -> 2 Sqrt[w2^2] + C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]} *)
```

It is not obvious (to me) why this change matters, because

```
0.5 == 1/2
(* True *)
```

**Addendum**

As noted below by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd), one of the two solutions derived here is spurious due to a bug in `DSolve`.  To show this, plug the two solutions in turn into the original PDE:

```
FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[l[w1, w2], w1]  w2/2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] w1/2 - w1] /. #] & /@ %%
(* {w1 (-1 + w2/Sqrt[w2^2]), -((w1 (w2 + Sqrt[w2^2]))/w2)} *)
```

Thus, only the first solution is valid for `w2 > 0`, and only the second for `w2 < 0`.  This error is related to the one discussed in more detail in [130857](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130857/1063).

**Update for Version 11.1.0**

With version 11.1,

```
Flatten@DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] 0.5 w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] w1/2 - w1 == 0, 
    l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}] // Simplify
(* {l[w1, w2] -> -2 Sqrt[w2^2] + C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)], 
    l[w1, w2] -> 2 Sqrt[w2^2] + C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]} *)
```

which is the machine-precision equivalent of the first result in this answer.  This certainly is a step in the right direction.  However, the problem remains only one of the two solutions is correct.

Comment: It might be the old "Rationalize" thing. I often bump into this sort of problem. I never get why some times it works and othertimes it doesn't.

Comment: @MirkoAveta  Your suggestion seems reasonable and was, in fact, my first thought.  However, the fact that `0.5 == 1/2` is `True` causes me to wonder.  I ran `Trace[]` on both versions but obtained no useful insight.  `Trace[]` with `TraceInternal->True` might be more informative, but would take a while to assess, because the output probably would be huge.

Comment: I just want to point out this solution has the same issue as the one you mentioned in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130857/1871), the correct solution is actually `l -> Function[{w1, w2}, -2 w2 + C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]]`

Comment: @xzczd  Yes, I somehow overlooked this connection.  Thanks.