# Spurious DSolve Solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier, persisting through 13.2.**

`DSolve` quickly returns solutions to the following PDE (which is the homogeneous portion of the PDE in question [130755](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130755/1063)).

```
s = Flatten@DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 - l[w1, w2] == 0, 
    l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}]
(* {l[w1, w2] -> E^(-(ArcTan[w1/Sqrt[w2^2]]/a)) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)], 
    l[w1, w2] -> E^(ArcTan[w1/Sqrt[w2^2]]/a) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]} *)
```

However, an attempt to verify this result indicates that one of the two solutions is spurious.

```
FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 - l[w1, w2]] /. #] &
    /@ s
(* {-((E^(-(ArcTan[w1/Sqrt[w2^2]]/a)) (w2 + Sqrt[w2^2]) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)])/w2), 
      (E^(ArcTan[w1/Sqrt[w2^2]]/a) (-w2 + Sqrt[w2^2]) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)])/w2} *)
```

The first term fails to vanish for `w2 > 0`, and the second term for `w2 < 0`.  Executing `SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce]` prior to `DSolve` in the hope of obtaining conditional answers produces the same result.  Also, using the `DSolve` `Assumptions` option does not help.  For instance,

```
sp = Flatten@DSolve[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 - l[w1, w2] == 0, 
    l[w1, w2], {w1, w2}, Assumptions -> w2 > 0]
(* {l[w1, w2] -> E^(-(ArcTan[w1/w2]/a)) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)], 
    l[w1, w2] -> E^(ArcTan[w1/w2]/a) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]} *)

FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 - l[w1, w2]] /. #] &
    /@ sp
(* {-2 E^(-(ArcTan[w1/w2]/a)) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)], 0} *)
```

Once again, one solution is spurious.  In fact, the correct solution is

```
l[w1, w2] -> E^(-(ArcTan[w1, w2]/a)) C[1][1/2 (w1^2 + w2^2)]];
FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[l[w1, w2], w1] a w2 - D[l[w1, w2], w2] a w1 - l[w1, w2]] /. %
(* 0 *)
```

My questions are, (1) is this a bug (as it appears to be)?, and (2) does a work-around exist (apart from changing independent variables to obtain an ODE instead)?

**Addendum**

As commented by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd), this problem also occurs in question [130596](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130650/1063).

Comment: The sample returns unevaluated now in v12.2 (Wolfram Cloud), not sure if it's an intentional change or backslide…

Comment: @xzczd  Thanks for the update.  It would not be the first time that a `DSolve` bug was "fixed" in this way!