# Why Mathematica gives this second solution to this first order linear PDE $w_t+3 t w_x=w$?

Tags: differential-equations

This is using V12 on windows 10.

I  was trying to verify my hand solution with Mathematica. `DSolve` gives two solutions instead of one, which I do not understand how it came up with. I also was not able to verify one of the two solutions it gives.

Here is the pde specification. Solve for $w(x,t)$

$$
         \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}+3 t  \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=w(x,t) \tag{1}
$$

with initial conditions $w(x,0)=f(x)$.

Here is the code (Using `w` in the DSolve instead of standard `w[x,t]` in order to get the solution using `Function` so to make it easier to verify)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
pde = D[w[x, t], t] + 3*t*D[w[x, t], x] == w[x, t];
ic = w[x, 0] == f[x];
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic}, w, {x, t}] (*Assumptions -> t > 0 has no effect*)
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the first solution above which I have doubts it is correct. Notice that adding `Assumptions -> t > 0` to `DSolve` has not effect. Same solutions are obtained.

Now, the second solution verifies OK, but not the first

```
 Assuming[t > 0, Simplify[pde /. sol[[1, 1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Assuming[t > 0, Simplify[pde /. sol[[2, 1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question is : Is the first solution above correct? If so, why it does not verify, and how did Mathematica obtain it? Is this a bug?

Below is hand solution.

### Appendix

my hand solution I was trying to verify using Mathematica:

Let $w\equiv w\left(  x\left(  t\right)  ,t\right)  $ then
\begin{equation}
\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial
w}{\partial t}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Comparing (1,2) shows that

\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{dt}  & =w\tag{3}\\
\frac{dx}{dt}  & =3t\tag{4}
\end{align}

Solving (3) gives

\begin{equation}
w=Ce^{t}\nonumber
\end{equation}

From initial conditions at $t=0$, the above becomes  $f\left(  x\left(
0\right)  \right)  =C$. Hence the above becomes

\begin{equation}
w\left(  x,t\right)  =f\left(  x\left(  0\right)  \right)  e^{t}\tag{5}
\end{equation}

From (4)

\begin{align*}
x  & =\frac{3}{2}t^{2}+x\left(  0\right)  \\
x\left(  0\right)    & =x-\frac{3}{2}t^{2}
\end{align*}

Substituting the above in (5) gives

$$
w\left(  x\left(  t\right)  ,t\right)  =f\left(  x-\frac{3}{2}t^{2}\right)
e^{t}
$$

Comment: Maple 2019.1 produces  $w \left( x,t \right) =f \left( -3/2\,{t}^{2}+x \right) {{\rm e}^{t}} $.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130857/1871

Comment: As a workaround you can add your own `VerifySolutions` with the assumption `t > 0`: 

`sol = Select[DSolve[{pde, ic}, w, {x, t}],
  Simplify[pde && ic /. #, t > 0] &]`

Comment: Actually, both solutions are correct, the first for `t < 0` and the second for `t > 0`.  As @xzczd commented earlier, this same problem occurred in 130857.  I reported the bug over two years ago, and Wolfram, Inc. still has not fixed it.