# These PDE's no longer evaluate in version 12.2 as they did under 12.1. What can be done to make them evaluate under 12.2?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, version-12.2

These 399 PDE's no longer produce result under Version 12.2 on windows. `DSolve` now returns unevaluated.  These all evaluated under version 12.1.

Why is that? And what can be done to make them evaluate again under Version 12.2?

**edit:**
I just finished the full report. These PDE's can be download in one plain text file from a link at the introduction section of this [report](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2020_2_and_mma_12_2/regression/mathematica_regression.htm)

A more complete report is also given in this [page](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2020_2_and_mma_12_2/index.htm)

**end edit**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(*1*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2-a^2*x^2+3*a)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*2*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^2*y+b*x^3+c)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*3*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^2*y+b*y^3)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*4*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*Sqrt[x]*y+b*Sqrt[y])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*5*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*Sqrt[x]*y+b*x*Sqrt[y])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*6*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+A*Sqrt[a*x+b*y+c]*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*7*)
pde=(a*x+b*Sqrt[y])*D[w[x,y],x]-(c*Sqrt[x]+a*y)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*8*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+b*x^k)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*9*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^k*y+b*x^n)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];
sol=Simplify[sol];

(*10*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y^2+b*x^n)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];
sol=Simplify[sol];

(*11*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+a*x^n*y+a*x^(n-1))*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];
sol=Simplify[sol];

(*12*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^n*y^3+3*a*b*x^(n+m)*y^2-b*m*x^(m-1)-2*a*b^3*x^(n+3*m))*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*13*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^n*y^k+b*x^m*y)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*14*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+(b*y+c*x^m)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*15*)
pde=a*x^k*D[w[x,y],x]+(y^n+b*x^m*y)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y},Assumptions->{n!=1}],60*10]];

(*16*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+b*y+a*(lambda-b)*Exp[lambda*x]-a^2*Exp[2*lambda*x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*17*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+a*Exp[lambda*x]*y-a*b*Exp[lambda*x]-b^2)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*18*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(Exp[lambda*x]*y^2+a*Exp[mu*x]*y+a*lambda*Exp[(mu-lambda)*x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*19*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]-(lambda*Exp[lambda*x]*y^2-a*Exp[mu*x]*y+a*lambda*Exp[(mu-lambda)*x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*20*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^n*y^2+lambda*y-a*b^2*x^n*Exp[2*lambda*x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*21*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^n*Exp[2*lambda*x]*y^2+(b*x^n*Exp[lambda*x]-lambda)*y+c*x^n)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*22*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^n*y^2+lambda*x*y+a*b^2*x^n*Exp[lambda*x^2])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*23*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+(a*x^(2*n)*Exp[lambda*x]*y^2+(b*x^n*Exp[lambda*x]-n)*y+c*Exp[lambda*x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*24*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+3*a*lambda-lambda^2-a*(a+lambda)*Coth[lambda*x]^2)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*25*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+lambda*(a+b)-2*a*b-a*(a+lambda)*Tanh[lambda*x]^2-b*(b+lambda)*Coth[lambda*x]^2)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*26*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+a*x*Log[b*x]^m*y+a*Log[b*x]^m)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*27*)
pde=x^k*D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y^n*Log[x]^m+b*y*Log[x]^s)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*28*)
pde=Log[lambda*x]^k*D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y^n+b*y*Log[x]^m)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*29*)
pde=Log[lambda*x]^k*D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y^n*Log[x]^m+b*y)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*30*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(y^2+a*x*Sin[b*x]^m*y+a*Sin[b*x]^m)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*31*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*ArcSin[lambda*x]^k+b)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*32*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(lambda*ArcSin[x]^n*(y-a*x^m-b)^2+a*m*x^(m-1))*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*33*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*ArcCos[lambda*x]^k+b)*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*34*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*ArcCos[lambda*x]^k*ArcCos[mu*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*35*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(lambda*ArcCos[x]^n*(y-a*x^m-b)^2+a*m*x^(m-1))*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*36*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+(x^(2*n)*f[x]*y^2+(a*x^n*f[x]-n)*y+b*f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*37*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*Exp[lambda*x]*y^2+a*Exp[lambda*x]*f[x]*y+lambda*f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*38*)
pde=D[f[x,y],y]*D[w[x,y],x]-D[f[x,y],x]*D[w[x,y],y]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*39*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==alpha*x+beta*y+gamma;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*40*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==c;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*41*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x+k*y;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*42*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x*y+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*43*)
pde=a*y^2*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^2*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x^2+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*44*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x*y^2+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*45*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y^m*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x^k+d*y^s;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*46*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+(b*x^m*y+c*x^k)*D[w[x,y],y]==s*x^p*y^q+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*47*)
pde=a*y^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^m*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x^m+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*48*)
pde=a*Exp[alpha*x]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[beta*y]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[gamma*x]+s*Exp[mu*y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*49*)
pde=a*Exp[beta*x]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[gamma*x+lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[mu*x+delta*y]+k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*50*)
pde=a*Exp[lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[beta*x]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[gamma*y]+d;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*51*)
pde=a*y^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[lambda*x]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[mu*x]+s;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*52*)
pde=a*Exp[lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^k*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[mu*x]+s;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*53*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sinh[lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Sinh[mu*x]^m+s*Sinh[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*54*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cosh[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Cosh[mu*x]^m+s*Cosh[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*55*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tanh[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Tanh[mu*x]^m+s*Tanh[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*56*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tanh[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Tanh[mu*x]^m+s*Tanh[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*57*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Coth[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Coth[mu*x]^m+s*Coth[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*58*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Coth[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Coth[mu*x]^m+s*Coth[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*59*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Log[lambda*x]*Log[beta*y]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[gamma*x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*60*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Log[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[mu*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*61*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Log[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[mu*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*62*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==b*Log[lambda*x]^k*Log[beta*y]^n;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*63*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+b*x^n)*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[lambda*x]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*64*)
pde=a*x^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[lambda*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^l;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*65*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sin[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Sin[mu*x]^m+s*Sin[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*66*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sin[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Sin[mu*x]^m+s*Sin[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*67*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cos[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Cos[mu*x]^m+s*Cos[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*68*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cos[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Cos[mu*x]^m+s*Cos[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*69*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tan[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Tan[mu*x]^m+s*Tan[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*70*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tan[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Tan[mu*x]^m+s*Tan[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*71*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cot[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Cot[mu*x]^m+s*Cot[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*72*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cot[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Cot[mu*x]^m+s*Cot[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*73*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcSin[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcSin[mu*x]^m+ArcSin[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*74*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcSin[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcSin[mu*x]^m+ArcSin[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*75*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCos[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcCos[mu*x]^m+ArcCos[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*76*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCos[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcCos[mu*x]^m+ArcCos[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*77*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcTan[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcTan[mu*x]^m+ArcTan[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*78*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcTan[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcTan[mu*x]^m+ArcTan[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*79*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCot[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcCot[mu*x]^m+ArcCot[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*80*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCot[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==a*ArcCot[mu*x]^m+ArcCot[beta*y]^k;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*81*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==y*f[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*82*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==y^2*f[x]+y*g[x]+h[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*83*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==y^k*f[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*84*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==Exp[lambda*y]*f[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*85*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==y^k*g[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*86*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(y+a)*D[w[x,y],y]==b*y+c;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*87*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(y*g1[x]+g0[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==y^2*h2[x]+y*h1[x]+h0[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*88*)
pde=y^k*f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+g[x]*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*89*)
pde=y^k*f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(y^(k+1)*g1[x]+g0[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==y^(3*k+1)*h2[x]+y^(2*k+1)*h1[x]+y^k*h0[x];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*90*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]+g[y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*91*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]*g[y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*92*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==g[x]*h[y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*93*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==f[alpha*x+beta*y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*94*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+y*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x^2+y^2];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*95*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+y*D[w[x,y],y]==x*f[y/x]+g[x^2+y^2];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*96*)
pde=x^2*D[w[x,y],x]+x*y*D[w[x,y],y]==y^k*f[alpha*x+beta*y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*97*)
pde=(f[x]*D[w[x,y],x])/Derivative[1][f][x]+(g[y]*D[w[x,y],y])/Derivative[1][g][y]==h[f[x]+g[y]];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*98*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*99*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*100*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+g[x]*y*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*101*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(g1[x]*y+g0[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*102*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(g1[x]*y+g0[x]*y^k)*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*103*)
pde=y^2*D[w[x,y],x]+a*x^2*D[w[x,y],y]==(b*x^2+c*y^2)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*104*)
pde=x^3*D[w[x,y],x]+a*y^3*D[w[x,y],y]==x^2*(b*x+c*y)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*105*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y^m*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*x^k+d*y^s)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*106*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+(b*x^m*y+c*x^k)*D[w[x,y],y]==(s*x^p*y^q+d)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*107*)
pde=a*x^n*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^m*y^k*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*x^p*y^q+s)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*108*)
pde=a*y^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*x^m+s)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*109*)
pde=a*Exp[lambda*x]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[beta*x]*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Exp[gamma*y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*110*)
pde=a*Exp[lambda*x]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[beta*y]*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Exp[gamma*y]+s*Exp[delta*y])*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*111*)
pde=a*Exp[beta*x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(b*Exp[gamma*x+lambda*y])*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Exp[mu*x+delta*y]+k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*112*)
pde=a*y^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Exp[lambda*x]*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Exp[mu*x]+s)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*113*)
pde=a*Exp[lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x^k*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Exp[mu*x]+s)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*114*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sinh[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Sinh[mu*x]^m+s*Sinh[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*115*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cosh[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Cosh[mu*x]^m+s*Cosh[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*116*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tanh[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Tanh[mu*x]^m+s*Tanh[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*117*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Coth[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Coth[mu*x]^m+s*Coth[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*118*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Coth[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Coth[mu*x]^m+s*Coth[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*119*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Log[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Log[lambda*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*120*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Log[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Log[lambda*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*121*)
pde=Log[beta*y]*D[w[x,y],x]+a*Log[lambda*x]*D[w[x,y],y]==b*w[x,y]*Log[beta*y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*122*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==b*Log[lambda*x]^k*Log[beta*y]^n*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*123*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+b*x^n)*D[w[x,y],y]==c*Log[lambda*x]^k*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*124*)
pde=a*x^k*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Log[lambda*x]^m+s*Log[beta*y]^t)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*125*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sin[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Sin[mu*x]^m+s*Sin[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*126*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sin[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Sin[mu*x]^m+s*Sin[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*127*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cos[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Cos[mu*x]^m+s*Cos[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*128*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cos[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Cos[mu*x]^m+s*Cos[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*129*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tan[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Tan[mu*x]^m+s*Tan[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*130*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Tan[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Tan[mu*x]^m+s*Tan[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*131*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cot[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Cot[mu*x]^m+s*Cot[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*132*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Cot[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*Cot[mu*x]^m+s*Cot[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*133*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcSin[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcSin[mu*x]^m+s*ArcSin[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*134*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcSin[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcSin[mu*x]^m+s*ArcSin[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*135*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCos[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcCos[mu*x]^m+s*ArcCos[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*136*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCos[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcCos[mu*x]^m+s*ArcCos[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*137*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcTan[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcTan[mu*x]^m+s*ArcTan[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*138*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcTan[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcTan[mu*x]^m+s*ArcTan[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*139*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCot[lambda*x]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcCot[mu*x]^m+s*ArcCot[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*140*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*ArcCot[lambda*y]^n*D[w[x,y],y]==(c*ArcCot[mu*x]^m+s*ArcCot[beta*y]^k)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*141*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]*y*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*142*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==(f[x]*y^2+g[x]*y+h[x])*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*143*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]*y^k*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*144*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]*Exp[lambda*y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*145*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==g[x]*y^k*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*146*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(y+a)*D[w[x,y],y]==(b*y+c)*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*147*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(g1[x]*y+g0[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==(h2[x]*y^2+h1[x]*y+h0[x])*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*148*)
pde=f[x]*y^k*D[w[x,y],x]+g[x]*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*149*)
pde=f[x]*Exp[lambda*y]*D[w[x,y],x]+g[x]*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*150*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==(f[x]+g[y])*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*151*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x]*g[y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*152*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+(a*y+f[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==g[x]*h[y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*153*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==f[alpha*x+beta*y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*154*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+y*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x^2+y^2]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*155*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==x^k*f[x^n*y^m]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*156*)
pde=m*x*D[w[x,y],x]+n*y*D[w[x,y],y]==f[a*x^n+b*y^m]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*157*)
pde=x^2*D[w[x,y],x]+x*y*D[w[x,y],y]==y^k*f[alpha*x+beta*y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*158*)
pde=(f[x]*D[w[x,y],x])/Derivative[1][f][x]+(g[x]*D[w[x,y],y])/Derivative[1][g][x]==h[f[x]+g[y]]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*159*)
pde=D[w[x,y],x]+a*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x,y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*160*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==f[x,y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*161*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+g[x]*y*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*162*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(g1[x]*y+g0[x])*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*163*)
pde=f[x]*D[w[x,y],x]+(g1[x]*y+g0[x]*y^k)*D[w[x,y],y]==h[x,y]*w[x,y];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*164*)
pde=(a1*x+a0)*D[w[x,y],x]+(b2*y+b1*x+b0)*D[w[x,y],y]==(c2*y+c1*x+c0)*w[x,y]+k2*y+k1*x+k0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*165*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+(b1*x+b0)*D[w[x,y],y]==(c1*x+c0)*w[x,y]+s1*x+s0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*166*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==lambda*Sqrt[x*y]*w[x,y]+beta*x*y+gamma;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*167*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==alpha*w[x,y]+beta*Sqrt[x]+gamma;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*168*)
pde=a*y*D[w[x,y],x]+b*x*D[w[x,y],y]==alpha*w[x,y]+beta*Sqrt[x]+gamma;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*169*)
pde=a*Sqrt[y]*D[w[x,y],x]+b*Sqrt[x]*D[w[x,y],y]==alpha*w[x,y]+beta*Sqrt[x]+gamma;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*170*)
pde=a*D[w[x,y],x]+b*D[w[x,y],y]==c*w[x,y]+k*x^n*y^m;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*171*)
pde=x*D[w[x,y],x]+y*D[w[x,y],y]==a*Sqrt[x^2+y^2]*w[x,y]+b*x^n*y^m;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*172*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==c*x^n*y^m*w[x,y]+p*x^k*y^s;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];

(*173*)
pde=a*x*D[w[x,y],x]+b*y*D[w[x,y],y]==c*(x^n+p*y^m)*w[x,y]+q*x^k*y^s;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde,w[x,y],{x,y}],60*10]];
```

Comment: Are the solutions for these 399 PDEs in _v12.1_ or earlier generally correct? Perhaps WRI has just abandoned unreliable algorithm? Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130857/1871

Comment: Should this be directly reported to WRI?

Comment: Seems like most of them still works on WolframAlpha, please report to WRI.

Comment: Import["DSolvePDE.mx"] File from 12.1.1 in 12.2.0 evaluates the above PDEs again. So the issue seems to be in DSolvePDE.mx! (/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86-64/DSolve/DSolvePDE.mx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for reporting the failure to solve these PDEs in 12.2.

The issue appears to have been caused by a recent bug fix for linear PDEs in DSolve.

We are working on a fix for the failure to solve these PDEs. Meanwhile, as a partial workaround for the problem, you could try evaluating the following lines of code before running the PDE examples.

```
Unprotect[DSolve`DSolveToSolutionInConditionalExpression];
Clear[DSolve`DSolveToSolutionInConditionalExpression];
DSolve`DSolveToSolutionInConditionalExpression[a_, __] := a;
```

I apologize for the confusion caused by this problem.

Comment: will this fix be implemented for all 12.2 users as an automatic update? It seems inconvenient to run these lines every time.

Comment: e.g. a paclet update for DSolve and the like?